Oracle Virtual Box vожно ли восстановить виртуальную машину имея только её снапшот?
В учебных целях упражнялся с созданием и изменением виртуальных машин в Oracle Virtual Box. В процессе случайно удалил всю папку с одной из машин с концами, остался только один её снапшот, который лежал в отдельной папке для снапшотов. При попытке восстановить машину по нему через регистрацию его как самостоятельного жёсткого диска программа выдаёт ошибку об отсутствии записи о таковом в медиа реестре.
Полный текст ошибки:
Не удалось открыть образ виртуального диска C:\Users\labyn\VirtualBox VMs\PureOS\Snapshots\{a71a841f-915d-4f84-ae09-301dd1d04de0}.vdi.

Parent medium with UUID {cb611132-2ea1-400a-9525-82a1fe732869} of the medium 'C:\Users\labyn\VirtualBox VMs\PureOS\Snapshots\{a71a841f-915d-4f84-ae09-301dd1d04de0}.vdi' is not found in the media registry ('C:\Users\labyn\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml').

Код ошибки:E_FAIL (0X80004005)
Компонент:MediumWrap
Интерфейс:IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
Вызванный интерфейс:IVirtualBox {7682d5eb-f00e-44f1-8ca2-99d08b1cd607}
Код ошибки метода:VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0X80BB0001)

Насколько я понял, проблема заключается в том, что снимок ссылается на виртуальную машину, которой уже нет в записях Virtual Box. Попытка создать её полную копию по настройкам не увенчалась успехом. Я не нашёл в интернете способа восстановить всё назад без наличия родительской виртуальной машины. Есть ли такой способ?

Снапшот хранит только изменения по сравнению с исходной машиной. Сам снапшот бесполезен без всей машины.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, получается в моём случае уже не возможно восстановить, даже если я сделаю полностью идентичную копию оригинальной машины, программа будет воспринимать её как совершенно новую, верно?

Верно. Вам надо попросить помощи в Virtual Box community. Возможно есть способ "наложить" снапшот на другую виртуальную машину и получить жуткое месиво из которого пытаться восстановить отдельные файлы. https://www.google.com/search?q=retrieve+files+from+virtual+box+snapshot.
